# How to use urlencode in PHP

Tags: php, urlencode

I'm trying to use urlencode to convert the string:  `<a href="<?php print 'search.php?query='.quote_replace(addmarks($search_results['did_you_mean'])).'&search=1'?>">`

Actually, I want to implement a search engine.

```
|-www
 |- index.php
 |- search directory
  |- search.php
  |- header.html
  |- search_form.html
  |- search_result.html
  |- footer.html
```

`search.php includes header.html,search_form.html,search_result.html etc.`

I access search.php using: `localhost/index.php/?page=search`

search_form.html include button to search. And it call search.php using: `<form action="index.php/?page=search" method="get">`. I'm not sure if it's right.

After submitting the search request, search.php calls search_result.html to show result. The code in search_result.html: 
`<a href="<?php print 'search.php?query='.quote_replace(addmarks($search_results['did_you_mean'])).'&search=1'?>"><?php print $search_results['did_you_mean_b']; ?>`

It seems should work, but after I click the search button, the result url is `index.php/?query=&search=1`. And I think it should be `index.php/?page=search/?query=&search=1`.

So, I try to use urlencode to solve it. And I don't know if the idea is right.

Comment: @ApoY2k, i have edited the post and try to explain it clearly. Can you help me try to find where is the problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$url = 'search.php?' . http_build_query(array(
    'query'  => $search_results['did_you_mean'],
    'search' => 1
));
```

That's the most simple way to go - please see [`http_build_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

I don't know what your functions `quote_replace()` and `addmarks()` do but when you run `urlencode("search.php?query=")` this will also encode the `?` and the `=` and will result in `search.php%3Fquery%3D` (same for `urlencode("&search=1")` which encodes the `&` and the `=` and will result in `%26search%3D1`) which in total will make the URL unusable.

Comment: +1 I had forgotten about this function, it is incredibly useful!

Comment: @Stefan, you figured how to use http_build_query(). Thanks

Comment: @Stefan, I just want to treat the `?`. But i'm totally lost in doing that. Can you help me?

Comment: This function would have came in handy years ago when I still did this sort of thing :\

Comment: @Mark, do you have any idea about that?

Answer (score 4):

urlencode is used like this:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/page?foo='.urlencode($foo).'&bar='.urlencode($bar);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Handle is a very generic word. The question mark that seperates the resource name from the query string needs no special treatment.

Comment: Question marks inside $foo or $bar get turned into encoded strings appropriately by urlencode.  That's what it's there for.